# Unity Quaternion Lerp method always returns the to value

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, math, quaternions

I've implemented the following very basic `Quaternion` `Lerp` method provided by the Unity API, where the `time` contains a `float` value going from 0.0 to 1.0. While expecting a transition between the `from` and `to` value, the `Lerp` method only returns the `to` value. Only when the `time` is `0`, the `Lerp` method returns the `from` value.

Am I missing something? The console clearly shows that everything should be working correctly. Thee snippet is directly copied from my project and is not changed for the question.

*Tested in Unity 2020.1.17 and Unity 2021.1.7*

*I've also tried the Quaternion's Slerp and RotateTowards methods, which gave the exact same results*

```cs
var lerped = Quaternion.Lerp (from, to, time);
Debug.Log ($"Time: {time}\t From: {from}\t To: {to}\t Lerped: {lerped}");
```

[image: Console output]

Comment: @nka_Zz no, I do not alter these values, as shown in the screenshot of the console.

Comment: this is not what the documentation describes https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Lerp.html

Comment: yeah forget what i said, you need to divide your time by some value to lower the overall lerp progession, as it seem to already overshoot, with the first update

Comment: If I understand you correctly, that would also not work, since the `Lerp` method immediately returns the `to` value, so it would make no sense to use it as the `from` value. That's not how Lerp methods should work. It should take a `from` and `to` value, and interpolate between these values based on the given time.

Comment: while the documentation uses Time.time, this is not really applicable in nearly every case, as this would mean that the lerp speed depends on when you start  the calculation. so if this calculation would be at the start of the application it would work, but if calculated at a later point it would calculate to the To value, since Time.time value would already be very big. Therefore better use Time.deltaTime and add the deltatime each update to the time value you use, if the lerp is then to slow or to fast multiply the time value by some number.

Comment: I could be wrong but `Quaternion.Lerp` and `".Slerp` might be returning normalised values, and because `from` is zero, the result is always equal to `to` (for `t > 0`).

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that the problem was that the `from` value was instantiated using `new Quaternion ();`. I expected this to be the same as `Quaternion.identity`. Even though the console showed a Quaternion of `(0, 0, 0, 0)` the Lerp was not able to handle it like it would handle a `Quaternion.identity` value (which console logs exactly the same).

LT;D'R; Use `Quaternion.identity` instead of `new Quaternion ();`